# Does node_load check security through organics group?

Tags: nodeload

Question: if I use the node_load api to read nodes on which there is an organics group, does Drupal check if I am a member of the authorized group?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. Following the rabbit hole you can check the source code of node_load [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7), which basically is just a call to [node_load_multiple](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7), which in turn is a call to [entity_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_load/7) - which actually loads the node.

Security should be implemented prior to this call, when defining which nodes to load, not when loading the nodes.

Hope this helps!